# How does git handle previously non-fast forward merges from a now deleted branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

So say I have my master branch, and I create feature-x branch to work on a new feature.  I do several commits into feature-x, rebase feature-x from master and then do a non fast-forward merge from feature-x branch to the master branch.

Now what happens to my commit history if I then delete the feature-x branch?

I am doing a non-ff merge because after reading an article (that I agree with) it's easier to keep track of feature specific changes and the full lifecycle of features by doing non-ff merges.

Comment: The important thing, between the two answers, is that a branch is merely a pointer to a given commit, nothing more. Deleting it doesn't delete commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your history after the merge looks something like this:

```
A-----------E
 \         /
  B---C---D
```

Here, D is the head of feature-x branch after the rebase and E is the head of the master branch after the merge. What happens to master when you delete the feature-x branch? Nothing. Branch is just a pointer to one specific revision (plus some additional data like the reflog) and when you delete it, all you lose is just the pointer, the master will stay exactly the same as it was before you deleted it.

That being said, I'm not sure why are you doing rebase *and* merge. If you want to keep the history clear, just use merge, you don't need to rebase.

Comment: Right but commits B, C, and D describe how feature-x were developed.  If i delete the branch does that mean I essentially lose the history of the individual commits for that feature and can only look at the final result?  Also I thought I had to rebase feature-x on master in case master had additional commits to it, so that feature-x was using the latest general code and lessened the chance for final merge conflicts

Comment: No, you don't lose that commits. The history will be the same. As svick said, you only lose the branch reference to the latest commit of the branch feature-x, but since you have merged all commits, they can still be reached from the master branch

Comment: @Kall, regarding rebasing, you certainly don't have to rebase. Rebasing and merging should end with the repo in the exact same state, it's just the history that will look different. And I don't think rebasing this way lessens the chance for merge conflicts, because git has to do pretty much the same merging in both cases. There is a difference though: with merge, you'll get one (potentially big and confusing) bunch of edit conflicts. With rebase, you'll get them in smaller chunks, one chunk per each commit with conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, they were really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens to the history, really.  You still have the same sequence (or really directed acyclic graph) of commits, and the branch name will still be included in the merge commit message.

You're just deleting a particular label for a particular commit.